# SAS: Merging two datasets with the same variable under a different name

Tags: merge, sas, rename

I've tried Searching for this question but I don't think it's been asked before.

I'm working on matching specific clients across two datasets. There's one variable in both datasets which has a unique identifier for each client, and this unique identifier is the same for each client across both datasets.

The issue is, the variable name for this unique identifier is different in both datasets, and so I'm not sure how I can go about merging them?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use the `rename=` data set option on either or both of the merging data sets until the key valued variables have the same variable name.

```
data one;
  do id = 1 to 10;
    x = id;
    if mod(id,3)=0 then output;
  end;
run;

data two;
  do myid = 1 to 10;
    if mod(myid,2)=0 or myid > 7 then output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  merge
    one
    two (rename=(myid=id))
  ;
  by id;
run;

data want;
  merge
    one (rename=(id=commonid))
    two (rename=(myid=commonid))
  ;
  by commonid;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retain the different variable name for the identifier, use sas proc sql.

```
    proc sql;
        create table mergeddata as 
        select a.*, b.* from mydata1 as a full join
        my data2 as b on a.someid1=b.someid2;
    quit;
```

Just a preference of mine, but I don't favor solutions the require modifying the underlying data in any way if there's a way to avoid this.

Comment: I've always preferred `proc sql` for small datasets, but avoided it for largish ones (1 GB+) because the proc sql performance was unreliable.

Comment: @Nickolay--I have not run into that problem, but that could be because I have been using server installs of SAS.  I also should mention that I have been also leaning toward proc sql because of portability.

Answer (score 2):

Rename one of the IDs to match the other `(rename=(id2=id))`  Full Example below:

Creating dummy data:

```
data t1; 
input id  Name $; 
cards; 
1 John
2 Jack
; 
run; 

data t2; 
input id2  title $; 
cards; 
1 Manager
2 Admin
3 Helpdesk
; 
run;
```

Rename ID2 to ID, then do the merge:

```
data megered;
merge 
    t1
    t2 (rename=(id2=id))
    ;
by id;
run;
```

Output:

```
 id=1 Name=John title=Manager
 id=2 Name=Jack title=Admin 
 id=3 Name=  title=Helpdesk
```